# get-aduser -filter {Displayname -like}

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble passing a variable with a wildcard to search AD against displayname filter.  If I put someones name followed by a wildcard it works correctly.  But not with a variable.  Any ideas?

```
    $data=import-csv C:\myscripts\listofnames.csv
    foreach($user in $data.displayname)
    {
      get-aduser -filter {(displayname -like "$user *")} -Properties displayname
    }
```

What am I missing?  if I don't do a -filter against Displayname and instead pipe a where-object displayname it works fine but takes forever that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the `-LDAPFilter` parameter instead.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(displayName=$user *)" -Properties displayName
```

Comment: omg that fixed it.  lol... I feel dumb now.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Refried04: It is a _workaround_ that _bypasses_ your problem, but your problem can be solved.